# Angular async pipe error: Argument of type 'any[] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: html, angular, pipe

I'm having this issue when using the pipe async in Angular inside an *ngFor. this is my code:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users | async | search:(filterValue | async)!">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Argument of type  'any[] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

I'm able to fix the last async inside de search pipe by using the "!" because I know it will never be null, but I can't manage to do the same with the first pipe, I know it will never be null too, how could I use the "!" with it too?

I already tried closing everything in parentheses and putting "!" on it, but it stops recognizing the user property on the let use of users

Comment: Have you tried like this let user of users! | async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this? I think this should work.

```
<li *ngFor="let user of (users | async)! | search:(filterValue | async)!">
```

Comment: I spent so long trying stuff, how did I not think of this, It's pretty obvious since it is applying it to users, you are awesome!

Comment: Another approach to solve this without a bang operator could be to use a fallback, like this: `(users$ | async) || []`